# Camel - RabbitMQ spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a xml file to rabbitmq using camel, and to start the route using spring boot. I am pushing this to cloudfoundry, and i get this error.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

     }
    @Bean
    public SpringCamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
        SpringCamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
        camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder());
        return camelContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteBuilder routeBuilder() {
        return new MyRouteBuilder();
    }



}
```

Homecontroller

```
@RestController
class HelloController {
    @Autowired AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/")
        public String home(Model model) {
            return "WEB-INF/index.jsp";
        }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/publish", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public void publish(Model model) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("Hi in publish 1");
            String message1Sent = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/camel-data/message1.xml"));
            // Send a message to the "camelqueue" queue
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("camelqueue", message1Sent);
             System.out.println("Hi in publish 2");

        }

}
```

Route

```
@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

//      from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/inputQueue?queue=camelqueue")
//      .to("log:com.wisegate.route.RabbitMQRoute?level=INFO");

          from("amqp:queue:camelqueue")
          .log("pushed the message to camelqueue");


//      // Trigger run right after startup. No Servlet request required.
        from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=10s").log("Camel timer triggered.");
    }
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xmlns:cloud="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf-spring.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud.xsd">                          
    <!--  <context:component-scan base-package="mr.f"/>  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- Obtain a connection to the RabbitMQ via cloudfoundry-runtime: -->
    <cloud:rabbit-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/> 

    <!-- Set up the AmqpTemplate/RabbitTemplate: -->
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/> 


    <!-- Request that queues, exchanges and bindings be automatically
         declared on the broker: -->
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/> 

    <!-- Declare the "messages" queue: -->
    <rabbit:queue name="camelqueue" durable="true"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="mr.f.spring_boot_camel">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"/>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Error. from cloudfoundry and local are same.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/mr/f/spring_boot_camel/config/MyRouteBuilder.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect] for bean with name 'org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:144)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:275)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect] for bean with name 'org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1357)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:671)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:447)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:417)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:525)
    org.springframework.boot.context.TypeExcludeFilter.match(TypeExcludeFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:341)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:280)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:144)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:275)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1402)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:671)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:447)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:417)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:525)
    org.springframework.boot.context.TypeExcludeFilter.match(TypeExcludeFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:341)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:280)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:144)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:275)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect

Looks like you have missed the `spring-aspects` dependency.